# Some Applications' Fonts are too Small

Tags: windows-10, fonts, microsoft-surface

I recently started using a Surface Book (This doesn't appear to be happening on my Win10 desktop). An application had text so small it was impossible to read, even when outputting to a large display:

[image]

I tried changing the font size in settings, and running `sfc /scannow` to check for corrupted system files, but neither fixed the issue.

I also considered that it was just the one program, but after encountering this on another application, I realized - after some research - this is a problem with Windows 8 apps running on Windows 10, but only on specific displays or possibly display settings.

This is probably happening for all surface users, as well as other laptops. [[Source](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/text-size-within-apps-in-windows-10-too-small/8d045904-2d25-4c66-adfc-f52f0bd37bbd)]

Answer (score 13):

I fixed the problem following steps 1. and 2. of @Travis but changing in step 3. So:

1. Make sure the application is running
2. Right-click on the icon in the task bar > properties

[image: Properties menu]

3. Tick `Override high DPI scaling behaviour. Scaling performed by:` and then select System (enhanced).

Comment: worked for me today with Photoshop CS4 on win11

Answer (score 7):

It took quite some time to dig up the solution on the Microsoft Message boards, so I figured I'd go ahead and post the question & answer for anyone else that may need it.

**1. Make sure the application is running**

**2. Right-click on the icon in the task bar > properties**

[image]

*The SAS Enterprise Miner software is a special case. After right-clicking the icon I had to right-click on the Java Web Launcher to get to the Properties.*

**3. Go to the compatibility tab > Disable display scaling on high DPI settings**

[image]

**4. Restart the application**

**5. The text should be a readable size now.**

[image]

*Note: I have a feeling there is another setting to fix this problem without having to do this for every application affected by it, although I have not found that answer yet.*

Comment: Setting "Change the size of text, apps, and other items" in "Display Settings" to something like 200% wasn't enough?

Comment: Yes, see the source I cited, a lot of people have the same issue.

Comment: Travis, thanks for pasting the solution it worked for me with little bit of difference. In task bar items i didn't got the properties to enable DPI settings. Instead in the desktop icons I right clicked and then to properties and then compatibility.
Desktop Icon --> Right click-->properties --> Compatibility--> Enable DPI settings option (In fact, it is disable display scaling on high DPI settings)

Comment: Currently, the settings for this can be found under Compatibility Tab > Settings Section > Click "Change high DPI settings button > Tick "Override hight DPI..." checkbox > Select "System (Enhanced)" option from drop-down list.