# Windows 10 unreadable small font in Windows Installer

Tags: windows-10, fonts

If I try to install something I get a window with text that is just too small to read.

[image]

I've already tried a few answers of other questions which are quite similar but without success:

[How do I fix the tiny font in my Windows 7 system dialog boxes?](https://superuser.com/questions/425449/how-do-i-fix-the-tiny-font-in-my-windows-7-system-dialog-boxes?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[Some Applications' Fonts are too Small](https://superuser.com/questions/1173048/some-applications-fonts-are-too-small/1173049?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I've also tried to change the screen resolution and scaling but that didn't change anything aswell. Maybe also related is that I use 2 screens 1 1920x1080 and 1 1440x900.

So I'm still unable to read the text but don't know how to make the font larger.

Comment: Have you tried changing the screen resolution experimentally?

Comment: Or the scaling? You may try, in increments (125%, 150%, 200%, ...), until the text is readable.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik and @ MichaelBay Updated the question

Comment: @MichaelBay even at 175% the font is still small compared to the rest of windows.

Comment: I'm afraid is something specific to this software that may not have a proper "fix". That said, as suggested above, you may try to temporarily reduce the resolution. That typically make things bigger.

Comment: @MichaelBay If it is specific for this software than it is the windows installer software as other installers have the same problem

Comment: Have you tried restoring font settings at Control Panel >  Programs > Font Settings?

Comment: @RaghuRanganathan If you mean under Control Panel > .. Personal settings > Fonts > Font settings then yes. Couldn't find the one you're referring to